# fractional scaling in the other direction

Tags: multiple-monitors, scaling

I am trying to set up my laptop to connect to my computer monitor, and my laptop has a higher dpi than my monitor. So I want to set my monitor to have a fractional scale of something like 75%, but all the options are 100% or higher. Is it possible to set the scale lower? Thanks!
[image: scale options]

P.S. I'm using 20.4
[image: system information]